# Tkinter Toplevel TypeError

Tags: python, button, tkinter, typeerror, toplevel

I am trying to create a new TopLevel through a button command, however, I am having some difficulty.  With the following code:

```
 initial_state_button = Button(current_state, text=current_state_text, command = partial(initial_state_display, aatsplusv))
 initial_state_button.pack(side = TOP)

....

def initial_state_display(dictionary):

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title = "About this State:"

    count = 0
    for key, value in dictionary["initial states"].iteritems():
        proposition = Message(top, text = key)
        proposition.grid(row=count, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        colon = Message(top, text = " : ")
        colon.grid(row=count, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        boolean = Message(top, text = str(value))
        colon.grid(row=count, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        count += 1
```

I receive the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__ return self.func(*args)
File "Assignmentest.py", line 400, in initial_state_display top = Toplevel()
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2136, in __init__ self.title(root.title())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have no clue what is wrong.  top = Toplevel is written exactly how the effbot example shows.  Is toplevel not available in Python 2.7?  If so, is there an 2.7 equivalent?

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Try `Toplevel(root)` (or whatever you called your master window, if not `root`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The line you're declaring `top`'s title is wrong. Your line

```
top.title = "About this State:"
```

should be something like this:

```
top.title("About this State:")
```

See [effbot docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) for further information.

---

Edit due to comment:

I just have a Python3 installation on my system but something like this blueprint should work. The code is not that nice but shows how to deal with toplevel windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from tkinter import *


def btn_callback():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Toplevel window")


root = Tk()
root.title('Main window')

b = Button(root, text="Open Toplevel", command=btn_callback)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

If you're using Python2 you should change `tkinter` into `Tkinter` and the code should work as desired.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing... I've altered that to its correct syntax, but I still get the same error.  Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @Bergy24: I just added a quick and dirty snippet showing how to deal with toplevel windows.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried using the example you've provided within my code and it still produces the same error, although when I run it on its own it works just fine.  Will try to provide more information when I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I think you should narrow down your code in order to find the reason for this error and remove unneeded overhead in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does anything change with `Toplevel(root)`?  Without a parameter, a hidden 'default Tk()' is created, and that can cause problems.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: I think you are mistaken. If there is already a root window and you call `Toplevel`, a new hidden "default Tk()" is not created. You only get a hidden window if you don't first create a root window. Whether you pass that root window in as a parameter or not is a separate issue (though it's good practice to pass it in)